# Installation of saned with systemd (no inetd or xinetd) - saned refuses connection

Tags: linux, networking, scanner, systemd, sane

I have set up a Raspberry Pi B v1 with a minimal Jessie image and configured it for printing via cups and scanning via saned.

The local setup is without issues; a

`pi@EMK-RPiBv1:~$ scanimage -L
device 'fujitsu:ScanSnap S1500:25959' is a FUJITSU ScanSnap S1500 scanner`

However, the scanner is not visible on the network. a `scanimage -L` on another machine shows
`emk2203@XPS12-9Q33:~$ scanimage -L
device 'hpaio:/net/HP_LaserJet_CM1415fn?ip=192.168.1.30' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_CM1415fn all-in-one
device 'hpaio:/net/HP_Officejet_Pro_276dw_MFP?ip=192.168.1.40' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_Officejet_Pro_276dw_MFP all-in-one`

So, the `scanimage -L` works - it finds the two other networked scanners, but **not** the scanner attached to the Raspi.

If I issue `netstat -tulpn` on the pi and check the status of `saned.service` and `saned.socket`, I get

```
pi@EMK-RPiBv1:~$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::6566                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN                    
tcp6       0      0 :::631                  :::*                    LISTEN      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42976           0.0.0.0:*                           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:29987           0.0.0.0:*                           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           
udp        0      0 192.168.1.34:123        0.0.0.0:*    -                       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*-                           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*-                           
udp6       0      0 :::35810                :::*     -                           
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*     -                           
udp6       0      0 :::49009                :::*     -                         
udp6       0      0 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe4:123 :::*     -                          
udp6       0      0 2a02:8070:a182:ce00:123 :::*     -                           
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*     -                           
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*     -                        

pi@EMK-RPiBv1:~$ systemctl status saned.socket
● saned.socket - saned incoming socket
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/saned.socket; enabled)
    Active: active (listening) since Sun 2015-10-11 20:01:52 CEST; 2min 18s ago
    Listen: [::]:6566 (Stream)
Accepted: 0; Connected: 0

pi@EMK-RPiBv1:~$ systemctl status saned.service
● saned.service - LSB: SANE network scanner server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/saned)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2015-10-11 20:01:53 CEST; 2min 26s ago
  Process: 342 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/saned start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

The open port is shown for tcp6 only, but according to `pi@EMK-RPiBv1:~$ sudo sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only` I get `net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0` - this shouldn't be a problem, since ipv6 is not bound to only v6, but includes ipv4 as well.

But when I try to telnet into the open port on the pi, the connection is **refused**:

```
pi@EMK-RPiBv1:~$ telnet localhost 6566
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

This indicates that I can't reach my saned.

If I kill the systemd service and socket for saned and try to debug, I get the following:

```
root@EMK-RPiBv1:~# systemctl stop saned.service
root@EMK-RPiBv1:~# systemctl stop saned.socket
root@EMK-RPiBv1:~# lsof -i :6566
```

So, nothing listening at the moment - no output.

```
root@EMK-RPiBv1:~# saned -d128 -a saned
[saned] main: starting debug mode (level 128)
[saned] read_config: searching for config file
[saned] read_config: done reading config
[saned] saned (AF-indep+IPv6) from sane-backends 1.0.24 starting up
[saned] do_bindings: trying to get port for service "sane-port"   (getaddrinfo)
[saned] do_bindings: [1] socket () using IPv6
[saned] do_bindings: [1] setsockopt ()
[saned] do_bindings: [1] bind () to port 6566
[saned] do_bindings: [1] listen ()
[saned] do_bindings: [0] socket () using IPv4
[saned] do_bindings: [0] setsockopt ()
[saned] do_bindings: [0] bind () to port 6566
[saned] do_bindings: [0] bind failed: Address already in use
[saned] run_standalone: spawning Avahi process
[saned] run_standalone: waiting for control connection
[saned] saned_avahi_callback: AVAHI_CLIENT_S_RUNNING
[saned] saned_create_avahi_services: adding service 'saned'
[saned] saned_avahi_group_callback: service 'saned' successfully established
```

What do I need to do to open the connection? Without installing inetd or xinetd, please. This should work with systemd alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper systemd cooperation is in SANE  1.0.25, SANE 1.0.24 has issues remaining. More on [SANE bug tracker](https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=314883). To get saned working with systemd, one should either use the sane-utils 1.0.25 version (not in Raspbian Jessie) or make adjustments to the 1.0.24 version.

In short, `libsystemd-dev` needs to be installed for the systemd glue to work, and the `saned.service` edited to match the man page suggestion for 1.0.25: [1.0.25 man page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1076042).

### Man Page for 1.0.25

Systemd configuration when saned is compiled without systemd support

This configuration will also work when Saned is compiled WITH systemd integration support, but it does not allow debugging information to be logged.

`saned.socket` (unchanged)

```
[Unit]
Description=saned incoming socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=6566
Accept=yes
MaxConnections=1

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

`saned@.service` (changed, works also if `systemd` support is compiled in, but doesn't allow logging of debugging information)

```
[Unit]
Description=Scanner Service
Requires=saned.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/saned
User=saned
Group=saned
StandardInput=socket

Environment=SANE_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/sane.d

[Install]
Also=saned.socket
```

You can also enter `Alias=saned.service` in the last install stanza after `Also=saned.socket` to have both saned references start with the same saned.*

Also, `/etc/default/saned` needs to contain `RUN=no` or the service fails, and as a reminder, the saned server address or **FQDN** (not just the server name) needs to be put in `/etc/sane.d/net.conf` on all client machines.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I try to telnet into the open port on the pi, the connection is refused:
>
> ```
> pi@EMK-RPiBv1:~$ telnet localhost 6566
> Trying ::1...
> Connected to localhost.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> Connection closed by foreign host.
> ```

But, um, *it's not refused*. If it was, you would see "Connection refused". But it clearly says "Connected" here – the connection was *accepted*, and then closed by the actual service.

Anyway: I can guess at two problems:

1. With inetd-like socket activation such as this, the saned service isn't running *until a connection is attempted*. Therefore it cannot appear in scan results either (since it's not running during the scan). So instead you might need to run it as a permanent service, not a socket-activated one.
2. Your `saned.service` is not a real systemd service; it was automatically converted from /etc/init.d/saned (as the "LSB:" prefix shows). As the init.d conversion needs to handle *many* weird edge cases, sometimes it results in services that are barely working – *especially* when combined with socket activation. Thus you should avoid starting saned's native-systemd units and LSB-converted units at the same time.

Comment: Your observation of telnet behaviour, coupled with 2., was right on the mark and helped me pinpoint the issue. Proper systemd cooperation is in SANE  1.0.25, SANE 1.0.24 has issues remaining. More on [SANE bug tracker](https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=314883). In short, `libsystemd-dev` needs to be installed for the systemd glue to work, and the `saned.service` edited to match the man page suggestion for 1.0.25: [1.0.25 man page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1076042). Also, `/etc/default/saned` needs to contain `RUN=no` or the service fails.

Comment: What stays the same is that the SANE server address or FQDN has to be explicitly  in the `/etc/sane.d/net.conf` on the client.